# Windows 8 App Development: can't change Display Mode in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: view, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, orientation

Currently I'm having an issue with Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I'm developing a simple Windows Store App by following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215600.aspx. Until this time, everything was working out fine.

However, at step 3, I'm being told to try out different view orientations. This should be done by heading to "Device" and selecting another view there. The problem is: all options within "Device" are **greyed out** (not selectable). So far, I haven't been able to figure out what the issue is.

I can't post images yet, so here is the [link to a screenshot](http://s14.postimage.org/6lvbyfwlt/Options_greyed_out.png).

*Extra information:*

- I'm running Windows 8 Enterprise (64 bit) on a 4GB RAM, 2.1 GHz Core2Duo System.

Are there any Windows 8 developers out there that could help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely it is because you are testing on the actual machine instead of the simulator.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/09/29/first-look-at-windows-simulator.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant kindly pointed out, I was testing on the local machine instead of in the simulator. Switching this fixed the issue. Thank you! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/09/29/first-look-at-windows-simulator.aspx